# Восстановление сайта на другом хостинге. Как повлияет на СЕО?

Tags: seo, хостинг

Есть просроченный сайт на хостинге. Нужно сделать точную копию сайта с повторением структуры и всего остального на новом хостинге. Как это повлияет на позиции сайта в поисковой выдаче?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если домен (доменное имя) останется прежним, а блэкаут продлится недолго, то практически никак.

Или домен таки изменится?